# JavaScript Function find and return largest number

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters, return

I'm attempting to create a function that takes two numbers, finds the highest one, and returns that.

When I run my code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var largest = function large(a, b) {
        var num1 = a;
        var num2 = b;
        
        if (num1 > num2) {
            return("num1" + num1 + " is greater");
            
        } else {
            return("num2" + num2 + " is greater");
        }
    }
        
    </script>
    
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));
    var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));
        largest();
        document.write(large);
    
    
    </script>
```

it returns everything, not the number. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I'm really sorry if this has already been posted in a slightly different way by someone else. I don't understand this well enough to know how to begin searching for what I need :/

Comment: You aren't using the result of the call to `largest`, nor are you passing required arguments to it

Comment: so how do i resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

- You are calling `largest()` but it's return value isn't being
  captured anywhere.
- When you do call `largest()` you don't pass the results of the two
  `prompt` statements as arguments to the function, which it requires
  as input.
- Whenever you are using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), you should always specify
  the second (optional) argument which specifies the "radix" (base
  numeral system) so that you don't inadvertently, get a converted
  value (like a hex or octal).
- You are trying to output `large`, which isn't the name your function variable uses. Just use a function declaration instead.
- You don't need to create new variables in the function that map to
  the arguments that were passed, just use the arguments.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    // No need to assign a named function to
    // another variable here. Also, see how the 
    // function includes a and b in its declaration?
    // That means that when you call it, you must pass
    // two values, the first will be known as "a" within
    // the function and the second will be known as "b"
    function largest(a, b) {
        // No need to set up new variables, just use
        // the passed arguments - - they are function variables
        if (a > b) {
            return a + " is greater";   
        } else {
            return b + " is greater";
        }
    }       
  </script> 
</head>
<body> 
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10);
    var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10);

    // Take the return value from the function call and write it
    document.write(largest(num1, num2));
  </script>
</body>
```

Now, your code also looks like it's from 1997 and you are doing a couple of things that shouldn't be done these days:

- `type="text/javascript"` is not requred.
- `document.write` should be avoided in all but a few cases as it causes anything already in the document to be thrown away and a new document created. Instead,
  access an existing element in the DOM and update it's content.
- It's generally better to place your `script` just before the closing
  `body` tag so that by the time the HTML parser reaches it, all the
  html in the `body` will have been parsed and available in memory.

```html
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  
  <script>
    function largest(a, b) {
        if (a > b) {
            return a + " is greater";   
        } else {
            return b + " is greater";
        }
    }
        
    var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10);
    var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10);
        
    // Take the return value from the function call and 
    // set that as the text of the <div> element in the <body>
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = largest(num1, num2);  
  </script>
</body>
```

And, the easiest solution to the "which number is greater" question is to just  use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

```html
<body>
  <div>The largest is: <span id="output"></span></div>
  
  <script>
    var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10);
    var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10);
        
    // Take the return value from the function call and 
    // set that as the text of the <div> element in the <body>
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = Math.max(num1, num2);  
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      var fun = parseInt(prompt("Write a number:"))
  var fun2 = parseInt(prompt("Write another number:"))
  function action(){
    if (fun > fun2){
      document.write("The greatest number is:" + fun);
    }
    else{
      document.write("The greatest number is:" + fun2);
    }      
  }
  action();
```

Comment: Please consider adding a little bit of information ( such as how are you solving the problem, an explanation of how it works, etc) rather than just sharing a snippet.